# Embed html in slack posts

Tags: javascript, html, slack

I have a html message like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(){
            document.writeln("<iframe src=\"http://www.example.com" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>");
        })();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>hello world!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i post this as a message in slack ? Does slack accept HTML ?

```
var message = {
        mrkdwn: true,
        text: "",      //This does not accept my above HTML code
        attachments : []
    };

    slacker.notify(message, function(err, result) {
        callback(err, result);
    });
```

Comment: https://api.slack.com/docs/formatting

Answer (score 20):

Slack doesn´t allow HTML elements. But you can format your text with its Markdown flavor, which allows (links, bold, italic etc)

It won't allow javascripts or iframes because of security.

Details : https://api.slack.com/docs/formatting

Comment: That's a bit misleading. Slack allows *no* HTML element at all. Links, bold, italic, code formatting is only possible by using a Markdown-like syntax.

Comment: Actually you can send these HTML tag by encoding them. Slack decoding this html tags and displaying on page. I will try it and update my answer. Thank you @LéoLam

Comment: markup is possible without url redirection:  https://slack.com/intl/en-in/help/articles/202288908-format-your-messages